# How to generate a biased coin with 1/3 probability of success using only "fair coins"

Tags: python

This is a problem on my homework:
Write a function (that takes no parameters) and generates a biased coin using only "fair coins"

I've found a solution which requires using a binary digit stream, since 1/3 in binary is 0.010101...
However, I'm wondering if there's a way to do solve this without using a binary digit stream? Here's the code for using a binary digit stream

```
def fairCoin():
    return random.choice([0,1])  

def oneThird():
   while True:
      yield 0
      yield 1

def biasedCoin(binaryDigitStream, fairCoin):
   for d in binaryDigitStream:
      if fairCoin() != d:
         return d
```

Comment: What have you tried so far towards your homework problem? This code you've posted seems to come from [this blog post](https://jeremykun.com/2014/02/12/simulating-a-biased-coin-with-a-fair-coin/). See [How to Ask and Answer Homework Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's not possible to generate 6 equally weighted probabilities only with coin-flips. You can only generate 2^n equally weighted probabilities, where n is the number of flips.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework problem with minimal effort put into it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I've understood the question correctly.

I'm going to use T for success, F for failure.  I've put the next bit in a code box to format correctly.  It shows what the outcome is and what the cumulative probabilities are if you reflip only for certain results.

```
.                                     T %       F %
First fair coin flip                  50%       50%
Reflip only if the result was T       25%       75%
Reflip AGAIN only if F                37.5%     62.5%
Reflip AGAIN only if T                31.25%    68.75%
etc, etc
```

Do you see where I'm going here?  If you do, go code it now.

You need a Reflip function that takes as arguments the result of the last flip and a fair coin.  It flips the coin and hands back the result if it's the same as the last result, otherwise it calls itself again with the new result.  The first call to it should use F as the initial result.  Theoretically, the function could go on infinitely, but that's what you need to generate 1/3 since it's not rational.